# grid item overlapping others in css grid on scale

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to build a css layout where, when hovering on an item, it scales up. The problem is that, as you can see on the image, it looks like the z-index is higher on the right and the bottom child.

An easy fix could probably be changing the z-index of each element, but the the list is rendered on react, so I can't change it on each child.

[image: Grid item overlapping example]

Comment: You could add the higher `z-index` value using css in the hovered item. `.item:hover {z-index: 10}` where you already have the css to scale-up the

Comment: Leonardo that's great,  I added it as an answer in case it helps others as well who might deal with the same issue, you can have a look at the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a higher value of z-index when hovering in your css where you have the scale-up transformation.

```
.item:hover {z-index: 10} // or a higher value depending the z-index of the other elements
```